# Links to Embedded entities in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following entities defined in my project:

**Country**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

}
```

**City**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    String name;
    @ManyToOne
    Country country;
}
```

**Person**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @Column
    String name;
    @Embedded
    Address address = new Address();
}
```

**Address**

```
@Data
public class Address {
    @Column
    String line;
    @ManyToOne
    Country country;
    @ManyToOne
    City city;
}
```

I have also repositories defined for `Person`, `Country` and `City`.

When I make a GET request to /persons/1 I get the following result:

```
{
   "name":null,
   "address":{
      "line":"Address1"
   },
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
      },
      "city":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/persons/1/city"
      },
      "country":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/persons/1/country"
      }
   }
}
```

I suspect that since address is an embedded object, the generated links to country and city are wrong. They don't return anything although `city` and `country` values are present. What should the correct links be?

Are embedded objects not supported by Spring Data Rest?

Comment: I don't suppose you're able to reach `/persons/1/address`?

Comment: It returns HTTP 400 Bad Request with the following message: PersistentEntity must not be null!

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions:

- move associations to the parent entity
- promote the embeddable into a separate entity resource
- add `ResourceProcessor` to remove those links
- add a custom controller to handle those links

**UPDATE:** This seems to be already fixed in Spring-DATA-REST v2.1. See [DATAREST-262](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-262).